# Python equivalence of Matlab lsqcurvefit() function

Tags: python, matlab, optimization, scipy

What is the equivalent or closest python, say SciPy, function to the Matlab function lsqcurvefit() which minimizes the square error between the data and a parameterized function (curve)?

I know scipy.optimize.curve_fit and scipy.optimize.leastsq are close. However, they do not use trust region relfective least square method. Of course, I can code the condition for switching between algorithms myself. But if there are existing python code, I do not have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: What is your end goal? Maybe this could be helpful: http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/scipy-user/2013-November/035192.html ?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/nmayorov/bounded-lsq/blob/master/bounded_lsq/trf.py. Its documented at https://nmayorov.wordpress.com/2015/06/19/trust-region-reflective-algorithm/.

Comment: +1 to @TrisNefzger's suggestion. This should be available in a future version of scipy. At the moment it's https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/5044

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[trf.py](https://github.com/nmayorov/bounded-lsq/blob/master/bounded_lsq/trf.py) by Nikolay Mayorov implements a trust region reflective algorithm for least-squares optimization as does Matlab's [lsqcurvefit()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqcurvefit.html) by [default](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqcurvefit.html#zmw57dd0e61022).

Both are based on the work of Thomas F. Coleman and Yuying Li:

1. "An Interior, Trust Region Approach for Nonlinear Minimization Subject to Bounds," SIAM Journal on Optimization, Vol. 6, pp. 418–445, 1996, available in PDF [here](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~tfcolema/articles/An%20Interior%20Trust%20Region%20Approach%20for%20Nonlinear%20Minimization%20Subject%20to%20Bounds.pdf)
2. "On the Convergence of Reflective Newton Methods for Large-Scale Nonlinear Minimization Subject to Bounds," Mathematical Programming, Vol. 67, Number 2, pp. 189–224, 1994, avaiable in PDF [here](https://ecommons.cornell.edu/bitstream/handle/1813/5485/92-110.pdf).

There are probably some differences in the actual algorithms implemented by Matlab vs. Mayorov as indicated in the latter's [blog](https://nmayorov.wordpress.com/2015/06/19/trust-region-reflective-algorithm/).

Comment: Thank you very much, Tris Nefzger! This is exactly what I am looking for. It seems that this code uses only the interior trust region reflective algorithm, without the switching between the aforementioned algorithm and the Levenberg-Marquardt method which is the algorithm used in the Matlab function lsqcurvefit(). Of course this is a minor issue compared to the implementation of the interior trust region reflective algorithm. We could just write a small code for switching ourselves. Would you agree?

Comment: @Hans: I suppose that is possible and would just as soon have separate functions which could import additional modules of shared or complex functionality such as trf.py imports from trust_region. Part of the reason for this is that the collection of arguments and options of some functions has grown too complex for my taste and I would prefer that a given functon is focused on doing just one thing in a narrower range. Anyway, I am not developing this and if you have suggestions for SciPy please subscribe to its mailing list at http://www.scipy.org/scipylib/mailing-lists.html.

Comment: Two small corrections:1) the updated version of this is (for now) in Nikolay's PR I linked in the comments. The version you linked to is not the final one. 2) the main entry point for users is supposed to be `least_squares`; trf.py is an implementation detail.

Comment: @ev-br: I looked thru https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/5044 but saw nothing about trust region reflective least square method which is the 'this' of the main question (SO 32261976). trf.py may be a relative detail in your bigger picture; trust_region.py should be included with it.

Comment: @TrisNefzger: clearly, trf.py is included in that PR, so it's unclear what you are saying.

Comment: @ev-br: Could you please point me, as a novice user of github and SciPy, to the following goals. 1) The right way to import this code by Nikolay Mayorov. Is it from SciPy.optimize import least_squares?  2) The path to find the aforementioned code and to inspect it? 3) Given a past version, say, https://github.com/nmayorov/bounded-lsq/blob/master/bounded_lsq/trf.py, how does one find the latest version of any particular code in GitHub/SciPy? Thank you.